# How can I check that a linear combination of integers can equal a particular value?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a set of integers $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$, how can I check that there exists a linear combination $x_1 a_1 + x_2 a_2 + ... + x_n a_n$ with non-negative coefficients $(a_i \ge 0)$ equal to a particular value $N$?

For example, if I have $x_1 = 4, x_2 = 2$, there exists a sum that is equal to $6$ ($4 \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot 1$), but there is no set of coefficients that will give me the value of $9$.

Comment: One required condition is that $\gcd(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \mid N$. Since $\gcd(4,2) = 2$, but $2 \not\mid 9$, is a reason you can't get $9$. Note this condition is required, but not sufficient, so even if it's met it doesn't guarantee there's a solution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem